# Is voice cloning allowed for non-commercial utilizations?

Tags: artificial-intelligence, right-of-publicity

When the uses of voice cloning (also known as audio deepfakes) are non-commercial, are they legal?

"Voice cloning" is a feature of speech synthesis systems that use a neural network. It allows users to make a voice sounding almost identical to the voice of a person by providing a sound recording of the person speaking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[united-states](/questions/tagged/united-states)

#### Short Answer

There must either be commercial benefit from using the imitated person's voice clone (under a right of publicity), or a harm caused in a commercial or non-commercial context as a result of someone relying upon the truth of the fake voice (under myriad different legal theories sounding in fraud), or some sort of intentional infliction of emotional distress or undue influence aspect to it use.

But if it is done for a non-commercial purpose and no one gets hurt by believing it to be true, it would usually be legal.

There are exceptions to fraud for unreasonable reliance. There are exceptions to all theories for parody or satire or exercise of a religion.

This said, this technology is at the frontier's of newly developing law and would present a case of first impression with no binding precedents to control the outcome in most U.S. jurisdictions.

#### Long Answer

There are multiple legal issues to consider. The main ones are addressed below.

**Right Of Publicity Claims**

You have accurately identified "right of publicity" as one of the key issues, but this varies greatly from one country to another and from one U.S. state to another within the United States.

However, almost all existing "right of publicity" laws and case law in the United States requires commercial appropriation of someone's likeness or other attributes. Accepting the question's assumption that this is a non-commercial use at face value, the deep fake wouldn't be covered by the right of publicity and the person whose voice was copied wouldn't have a right to sue on that basis.

**Non-Commercial Fraud And Deceptive Practices And Defamation**

This said, it could also present grounds for a false advertising claim, either under the Lanham Act, under a state deceptive practices act (i.e. consumer protection law), under a common law fraud theory, or under a charitable fraud criminal offense. In the case of a civil lawsuit on these theories, the person with the right to sue would be the person deceived by the deep fake and harmed into acting as they otherwise wouldn't have by the act, although reliance and harm could be presumed in a criminal case or a civil action by an attorney general or a private individual acting in the capacity of an attorney general.

In the same vein, there could be criminal consequences for using a deep fake of a living person for non-commercial purposes such as election fraud, or extorting someone to have sex (in which the deep fake would feign the imitated person was in peril), or providing a fake reference for an immigration application, or to gain access to national security secrets or military facilities in order to commit terrorism.

The living person whose voice was imitated might, in some contexts, also have  a right to sue for defamation, which in U.S. law, is a form of fraud, because it involves only false statements of presently existing facts or implied false statements of presently existing facts.

For example, is a deep fake voice clone of a living person was used to falsely tell people that the imitated person was confessing to having a sexually transmitted disease and that so many people were impacted that private calls wouldn't suffice to alert everyone, this might give that person a claim for defamation against the voice cloner.

**Unreasonable Reliance Based Exceptions In Fraud Cases**

In the case of fraud based theories (as opposed to right of publicity, or intentional infliction of emotional distress. or undue influence theories) presumes that reliance on the authenticity of the deep fake is reasonable. A deep fake of Einstein or FDR or JFK or MLK, Jr. or John Lennon (all of whom are famous people widely known to be dead many decades ago) endorsing an electric car or a social media service, for example, wouldn't be actionable because it wouldn't be reasonable for a listener to believe that it was real.

Neither would a deep fake used in a Saturday Night Live (late night comedy TV show) segment, where a listen has a heightened expectation that what they are being told isn't true (even if it theoretically could be true).

**Intentional Infliction Of Emotional Distress And Undue Influence Theories**

I could even imagine a deep fake of a dead person's voice directed at someone who believed in ghosts to influence a modern day Ebenezer Scrooge, in style of the ghosts in [Charles Dickens' "A Christmas Carol"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_Christmas_Carol), or to have a deep fake of a deceased spouse rebuke a vulnerable widow, might even state a tort claim for intentional infliction of emotional distress (a.k.a. "outrageous conduct"), or could be a basis for invalidating a transaction or will or trust induced by the encounter on an "undue influence" theory.

**First Amendment Exceptions**

If this were part of a satire or parody (even if any of these uses of the deep fake were commercial in nature, due to First Amendment Speech  concerns, as incorporated against state and local governments where appropriate through the due process clause of the 14th Amendment), there would be no liability.

Similarly, a deep fake used in the context of a religious ceremony or context, even if it is meant to be deceptive and is wrongfully relied upon, especially on a religious issue (e.g. the correctness of Shiite v. Sunni Islam, or Catholicism v. Protestantism), might very well be protected from legal sanctions by the Free Exercise Clause of the First Amendment to the United States Constitution (and incorporated against state and local governments under the due process clause of the 14th Amendment to the United States Constitution where state or local laws are involved).