# Are people's face/voice copyrighted by default?

Tags: copyright, fair-use, is-x-legal, artificial-intelligence, right-of-publicity

As you may know there are some AI apps that can clone anybody's voice (turn your voice to their voice), or there are some face swap apps you can replace your face with somebody else's face and make a video of it.

I am wondering is it legal doing such a thing for fun to make Youtube videos for example? Also monetize those videos and make money out of it?

Can we consider this kind of usage as a fair use?

Comment: Relared and arguably a duplicate: https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/99869/is-voice-cloning-allowed-for-non-commercial-utilizations

Comment: @ohwilleke: I am asking about commercial purposes

Comment: So, the right of publicity discussion isn't the same, but everything else would apply.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

People's voices and faces are not copyrighted. People have a right of publicity that bars commercial use of these things without compensation in some jurisdictions, but the parameters vary.

There are also potential issues of fraud.

Comment: Of course, if there was such a copyright, it wouldn’t belong to you, it would belong to your parents as the creators;you are just the tangible form. And maybe your hairdresser.